# Physiological or molecular difference before and after sleep?

Tags: physiology, sleep

I know that the details of the process of sleep aren't entirely known, but have always wondered why I feel rested after sleep.

**Biologically, what differences can be directly observed in the human body before and after a good night's sleep?**

Comment: Can you be any more specific? Sleep affects every single organ and organ system in the body, and everything from hormone levels to cytokine levels change from tissue to tissue based on the amount of sleep you get. 

Your question is almost impossible to answer concisely.

Comment: Similar: http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/3028/6422